# What is envers @AuditMappedBy() supposed to do?

Tags: hibernate, annotations, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate-Envers 4.3.11 Final

I see that the documentation says:

> To properly audit such relations with Envers, you can use the
>   @AuditMappedBy annotation. It enables you to specify the reverse
>   property (using the mappedBy element). In case of indexed collections,
>   the index column must also be mapped in the referenced entity (using
>   @Column( insertable=false, updatable=false ), and specified using
>   positionMappedBy. This annotation will affect only the way Envers
>   works. Please note that the annotation is experimental and may change
>   in the future.

What does the docs mean when it says **"specify the reverse property"**?

I have several entities that have collections with *ManyToOne* and *ManyToMany* links and I want to audit the entities and their relations and be able to retrieve revisions. But I can't seem to be able to traverse through the data down to the collections of the child entities that I'm retrieving, so I am guessing I am not auditing the relation between entities correctly?

So I think I need to use `@AuditMappedBy()`.

But I am confused because whether I use `@AuditMappedBy(MappedBy = "NAME")` on the columns that are the collections or `@audited` at the top of my entities, I see the same results in the audit tables and in the data when I retrieve my entities. I have yet to see why I would use @AuditMappedBy().

Can someone help me understand a use case for `@AuditMappedBy()`?

Example of the hierarchy of table and how I need to traverse to collections in child tables:

```
**TABLE A:**

@Entity()
@Audited
@Table(name = "TABLE_A")

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
private String name;

@OneToMany(
            mappedBy = "table_a",
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
    )
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
            {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN}
    )
    private Collection<TABLE_B> table_b = new ArrayList<TABLE_B>();




**TABLE B:**


@Entity()
@Audited
@Table(name = "TABLE_B")

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
private String name;

@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_TABLE_B", nullable = false)
private TABLE_A table_a;

@ManyToOne(
        cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
        {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE}
)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_TABLE_C")
private TABLE_C table_c;

@ManyToOne(
        cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
        {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE}
)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_TABLE_D", nullable = true)
private TABLE_D table_d;



**TABLE C:**

@Entity()
@Audited
@Table(name = "TABLE_C")

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
private String name;


@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "table_c",
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.REMOVE})
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
        {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE,
                org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE,
                org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN}
)
@XmlTransient
private Collection<TABLE_B> table_b = new HashSet<TABLE_B>();



**TABLE D:**

@Entity()
@Audited
@Table(name = "TABLE_D")

@Column(name = "ID")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "NAME", length = 50)
private String name;

@XmlTransient
@OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "table_d",
        cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST}
)
private Collection<TABLE_B> table_b = new ArrayList<TABLE_B>();
```

Comment: Can you update your post to specify the version of Envers and an example of an entity mapping where the traversal isn't working for you?  The `AuditMappedBy` isn't always necessary and it depends a bit explicitly on your use cases.